# Oauth2.json file while using youtube's API to insert videos in a playlist

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I am trying to use the following code to insert videos using youtube's API. I have generated my client secret file, however, could not understand how the oauth2.json file is generated.

```
import httplib2
import os
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
from oauth2client import tools



# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "my_client_secret.json"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json 
file
found at:

%s

with information from the Cloud Console
https://cloud.google.com/console

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please 
visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-
library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                       CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
YOUTUBE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


def get_authenticated_service():
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=YOUTUBE_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)
    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage)

    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
        http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


def add_video_to_playlist(youtube,videoID,playlistID):
  add_video_request=youtube.playlistItem().insert(
  part="snippet",
  body={
        'snippet': {
        'playlistId': playlistID, 
      'resourceId': {
              'kind': 'youtube#video',
          'videoId': videoID
        }
    #'position': 0
    }
}).execute()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    youtube = get_authenticated_service()
    add_video_to_playlist(youtube,"yszl2oxi8IY","PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-J8funQ")
```

How do I generate the OATUH2.JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `<yourscript>-oauth2.json` is used to store credentials (access token, refresh token, id token, token expiration date etc...)

From [google API client guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) :

> The oauth2client.file.Storage class stores and retrieves a single
>   Credentials object. The class supports locking such that multiple
>   processes and threads can operate on a single store.

If the file doesn't exist or the credentials in it are invalid the authentication flow is run :

```
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage)
```

Thus, if this file already exists and contains valid credentials, it won't be necessary to request an authorization code (through user registration and user accepting scope) to get a first access token since it will use the existing access token/refresh token in this file to hit Google API.

You can read more about `oauth2client.tools.run_flow` [here](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.tools.html)